# Windows 8 upgrade from XP - error "text not found"

Tags: windows-8-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from Win XP to Win 8. After I click "check out", I get the page for entering my name, email, address and phone number. When I enter all these details and click "Next" I get a "text not found" message just above the "State/Province/Prefecture" drop down. This is a screenshot, I have obscured my personal details but in reality I have entered all the required details correctly:

[image]

Does anyone have any clue on how to proceed?

Comment: Sounds like it's broken: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/error-text-not-found-in-windows-8-upgrade/e9f829bd-4dc1-4277-b140-27a6683e2116

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug indeed.

The only thing I can suggest is to make sure your info is precisely as in your billing address - case, spacing, etc. Check your statements. Arvato is looking it up with your credit card supplier. It may not have the intelligence to recognize variations in format. The State error may be misleading is its where the code fails rather than where the error is. That's just a guess but it's just a pick list...

Is there a way to pay for this separately, then put the purchase key in during the install?